# Solving $(1+x^2)y' - 2xy = (1+x^2)\arctan(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm asked to solve the differential equation: $$(1+x^2)y' - 2xy = (1+x^2)\arctan(x).$$

I rewrite it: 
$$y' - \frac{2x}{1+x^2}y = \arctan(x).$$
The integrating factor is: 
$$e^{-\int{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}dx} = e^{-\ln{1+x^2}} = (e^{ln{1+x^2}})^{-1} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$ 
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}y' - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}y = \arctan(x)\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{1+x^2}y) = \arctan(x)\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
**So to solve this equation I need to find the primitive of** 
$$\arctan(x)\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
**But I don't think I can do that yet, is there any other way to solve this differential equation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$

so that

$$
\int dx\; \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+ x^2} = \int dx\; \arctan(x) \frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x) = \int dx\; \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan^2(x)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\arctan^2(x) + c
$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $\arctan$ is $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$.

Now, observe that for a differentiable function $f$, we have:

$$\int f(x)f'(x)\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}(f(x))^{2}+K$$

where $K\in\mathbb{R}$. Taking $f=\arctan$, we deduce what you asked.

Comment: Thank you! Greatly appreciated.